# react native expo launch app time out

Tags: react-native

Using create react native app, I get this error when I scan the QR code from the package manager:

**java.net.SocketTimeoutException - connect timed out**

I have my Samsung s8 connected via USB, I can see the following json when I browse to the address using http instead of exp:

```
{"sdkVersion":"23.0.0","name":"tester1","slug":"tester1","version":"0.1.0","xde":true,"developer":{"tool":"crna","projectRoot":"C:\\sites\\tester1"},"packagerOpts":{"hostType":"tunnel","lanType":"ip","dev":true,"strict":false,"minify":false,"urlType":"exp","urlRandomness":null},"env":{},"bundleUrl":"http://169.254.140.132:19001/./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=C:\\sites\\tester1\\node_modules\\expo\\tools\\hashAssetFiles","debuggerHost":"169.254.140.132:19001","mainModuleName":"./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry","logUrl":"http://169.254.140.132:19000/logs","id":"@anonymous/tester1-e649dd6c-008d-4356-a9eb-0f80bb8a6a98"}
```

Can anyone please help? I've spent ages trying to get this working

Comment: It's hard to reply without much information.

(1) Did you generate the project using `create-react-native-app`?

(2) How did you run the development server?

(3) Where are you scanning the QR code from? An actual device? What device? The device must be connected to the same network as the development server.

Comment: Thanks updated  question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled my other connections. Expo was defaulting to the wrong IP.

Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections